# Validators.minlength is not working in angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I created a simple form in angular. I used two validations. The required validation works fine, but the minLength is not working.

Here is the html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="preferenceForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="overs" class="form-label">Number of overs</label>
            <input type="number" formControlName="overs" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.overs.errors }"
                   id="overs" placeholder="Overs..">
            <div *ngIf="submitted && f.overs.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="f.overs.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
              <div *ngIf="f.overs.errors.minlength">Choose at least 3 overs</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="players" class="form-label">Number of players per team</label>
            <input type="number" formControlName="players" class="form-control"
                   [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.players.errors }" id="overs" placeholder="Players..">
            <div *ngIf="submitted && f.players.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="f.players.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
              <div *ngIf="f.players.errors.minlength">Choose at least 3 players</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" formControlName="lastMan" type="checkbox" value="" id="last-man"/>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="last-man"> Last Man Standing</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center b-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light">Let's Start</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

and here is my component code:

```
export class NewMatchComponent implements OnInit {
  public preferenceForm: FormGroup;
  public submitted = false;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private appService: 
AppService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.preferenceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      overs: [8, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      players: [8, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      lastMan: [true]
    });
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
  get f() {
    return this.preferenceForm.controls;
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    console.log(this.preferenceForm.value);
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.preferenceForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    // const formData = this.preferenceForm.value;
    // this.appService.createNewMatch(formData.overs, 
formData.players, formData.lastMan);
  }

}
```

I used the validators correctly, I also used minlength in form, still not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Validator is working just fine,

> **minLength**Validator that requires the length of the control's value to be greater than or equal to the provided minimum length. This validator is also provided by default if you use the the HTML5 minlength attribute. Note that the minLength validator is intended to be used only for types that have a numeric length property, such as strings or arrays. **The minLength validator logic is also not invoked for values when their length property is 0 (for example in case of an empty string or an empty array)**, to support optional controls. You can use the standard required validator if empty values should not be considered valid. Source [minLength()](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#minlength)

Basically you are using the wrong validator. Change your Validator to `Validator.min(3)`

> **min**Validator that requires the control's value to be greater than or equal to the provided number. The validator exists only as a function and not as a directive.

See [this demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vsfm7m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)